# How to get full date in android?

Tags: java, android, calendar

I know about to get the date in android with the help of the calender instance.

```
 Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

 System.out.println("====================Date is:"+ c.get(Calendar.DATE));
```

But with that i got only the number of the Date. . . 
In My Application i have to do Some Calculation based on the Date Formate. Thus if the months get changed then that calculation will be getting wrong.
So for that reason i want the full date that gives the Month, Year and the date of the current date. 
And what should be done if i want to do Some Calculation based on that date ?
As like: if the date is less then two weeks then the message should be printed. . .

Please Guide me in this.
Thanks.

Comment: see http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html, it will help you to get full functionality of date

Comment: for all values in one variable as I suggested you can use Claendar.getMilliSeconds(), this will gives you current time in milli seconds, after getting that you can use that for made calculation.

Comment: @user370305: May be your view is better for my application to calculate. Now i want to check whether the current day is less then two weeks or not ? if yes then print the message. .  Then how should i have to do ?

Comment: have you a last date? means, for comparision I think you have a two dates one is current date from device and the other is the last 2 week date?. m I right?

Comment: Yes. .   The other one may be less then two weeks. But if the date is more then last two weeks then i want to print the message so how to do it ?

Comment: Look at my newly edited answer. And now to accept is as correct is your job. Thanks :-)

Comment: its for just calculation. Take whatever you want. If you want to take day then just take it. and if this is correct then please accept as a correct answer. Thanks

Comment: forgot the first edited. just use the code i give in second edit.

Comment: I edited my answer, just look at the second edit I have made small changes in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class,

```
String date = SimpleDateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date());
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at here,

```
Date cal=Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
String date = SimpleDateFormat.getDateInstance().format(cal);
```

for full date format look [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

and IF you want to do calculation on date instance I think you should use, Calendar.getTimeInMillis() field on these milliseconds make calculation.

EDIT: these are the formats by SImpleDateFormat class.

```
String[] formats = new String[] {
  "yyyy-MM-dd",
  "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm",
  "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mmZ",
  "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ",
  "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ",
 };
for (String format : formats) {
   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.US);
   System.err.format("%30s %s\n", format, sdf.format(new Date(0)));
   sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
   System.err.format("%30s %s\n", format, sdf.format(new Date(0)));
}
```

EDIT: two date difference  (Edited on Date:09/21/2011)

```
String startTime = "2011-09-19 15:00:23"; // this is your date to compare with current date 

            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); 
            Date date1 = dateFormat.parse(startTime);

     // here I make the changes.... now Date d use a calendar's date 

           Date d = Calendar.getInstance().getTime(); // here you can use calendar beco'z date is now deprecated ..

           String systemTime =(String) DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", d.getTime());

           SimpleDateFormat df1;

           long diff = (d.getTime() - date1.getTime()) / (1000);

           int Totalmin =(int) diff / 60;
           int hours= Totalmin/60;
           int day= hours/24;
           int min = Totalmin % 60;
           int second =(int) diff % 60;


if(day < 14)
 {
  // your stuff here ... 
  Log.e("The day is within two weeks");
 }
 else
  {
   Log.e("The day is more then two weeks");
  }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Ok. Nice One Stuff. . .  But should i have to count that min and second for calculation ? beause may be there is no need of it.

Comment: its for just calculation. Take whatever you want. If you want to take day then just take it. and if this is correct then please accept as a correct answer. Thanks

Comment: With Use of your first edited answer, I got the System error and got date as like 1970-01-01 05:30:00   I dont know where is the Problem. Will you explain me about it ?

Comment: forgot the first edited. just use the code i give in second edit.

Comment: Will you please update the Anwer with the Calendar use Because while i am going to calendar it gives me error that it Shoul be of integer as like. .  So please help me and then i will accept ur  answer.

Comment: @iDroid Explorer - I edited my answer, just look at the second edit I have made small changes in it.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
//try different flags for the last parameter 
DateUtils.formatDateTime(context,System.currentTimeMillis(),DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_DATE);
```

for all options check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
  int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
  int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
  System.out.println("Current date : " 
  + day + "/" + (month + 1) + "/" + year);
  }
```

Comment: I want all the Variables in to One variable So that i can easily done calculation.

Comment: what calculation you have to do?

Comment: Actualy i want to Do Some Action if the Past stored date is less then 2 weeks.

Comment: if you want date before two weeks then add this code c.add(Calendar.DATE, -(4*7));. After this the calendar will be on before two weeks.

Comment: Yes, May be you r right. But listern. I want to store the current date and compare that date with the any other date. If the the Other date is less then 2 weeks then i want to print the message. How i can achieve this ? Please guide me in this.

Comment: ya you can compare by using  long diff=calendar2.getTimeInMillis()-calendar1.getTimeInMillis();   int days=diff/(24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));  if(days>14){//print msg};

Answer (score 1):

I'm using following methods to get date and time. You can change the locale here to arabic or wot ever u wish to get date in specific language.

```
public static String getDate(){
    String strDate;
    Locale locale = Locale.US;
    Date date = new Date();
    strDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.DEFAULT, locale).format(date);

    return strDate;
}

public static String getTime(){
    String strTime;
    Locale locale = Locale.US;
    Date date = new Date();
    strTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.DEFAULT, locale).format(date);

    return strTime;
}
```

you can get the value and save it on String as below

```
String Date= getDate();
String Time = getTime();
```